# How do I enable the In-App Purchases capability only for specific build configurations?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, xcode8, code-signing-entitlements

We are building an app for a client, whose app id has the In-App Purchase entitlement.

When we send builds to them, we use their provisioning profiles/signing certs and all is well.

However, for our internal testing, we'd like to use our team's wildcard profile to get access to all of our testing devices. IAP testing is not usually a concern.

With Xcode 7 we were able to do this while getting around the IAP entitlement restriction, but **now with Xcode 8** I can no longer build and run using our wildcard profile because it checks for IAP capability pre-build.

So I've added an entitlements plist file to the project, but I'm unsure of the right key to use to set it either way.

Can the IAP capability be enabled/disabled per build configuration?

- I cannot find the relevant key here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html
- I could enable/disable IAP manually whenever needed, but this require either committing my changes every time **OR** trying to avoid committing the changes every time.

Comment: you could modify the plist during build in a build script step that takes into account the build configuration

Comment: @john_ryan Which plist? If you're referring to entitlements.plist, then which key do I set in that file?

Comment: I'd really like a solution to this, but it seems the only thing that changes in the repo is the 'pbxproj' file when enabling/disabling IAP. This means the only way to alter that would be in the final app package, ideally before signing. If I ever figure it out, I'll post an answer here ;-)

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? @charles

Comment: Alas no @StefanWallin :(